# Detect touchpad vs mouse in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mouse, touchpad, trackpad

Is there any way to detect if the client is using a touchpad vs. a mouse with Javascript?

Or at least to get some reasonable estimate of the number of users that use touchpads as opposed to mice?

Comment: @apsillers: Touch-pad mouse device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the general case, there is no way to do what you want.  ActiveX *might* allow you to see and examine USB devices, but in the best case, even if that is somehow possible, that limits you to IE users.  Beyond that, there is no way to know.

You might be able to discern patterns in how (or how often) a touchpad user moves the cursor versus how a mouse user might move the cursor.  Differentiating between physical input devices in this way is an absurdly difficult prospect, and may be wholly impossible, so I include here it for completeness only.

Answer (score 31):

The answer above by Lauri seems to work, but it took me a while to understand *why* it works. So here I'll provide a slightly more human readable version, along with a conceptual explanation. First, that same code written out in a human readable manner:

```
function detectTrackPad(e) {
  var isTrackpad = false;
  if (e.wheelDeltaY) {
    if (e.wheelDeltaY === (e.deltaY * -3)) {
      isTrackpad = true;
    }
  }
  else if (e.deltaMode === 0) {
    isTrackpad = true;
  }
  console.log(isTrackpad ? "Trackpad detected" : "Mousewheel detected");
}

document.addEventListener("mousewheel", detectTrackPad, false);
document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", detectTrackPad, false);
```

This works because wheelDeltaY measures the physical distance that the actual hardware mouse wheel has travelled, while deltaY measures the amount of scrolling produced on screen. A conventional mouse typically has a much lower "scroll resolution" than a trackpad. That is to say, with a trackpad you can make a tiny motion and a get a tiny scroll on screen. A conventional mouse scrolls in chunkier, low resolution clicks. To complete a full rotation of the mouse wheel, it might make 10 clicks. There is no such thing as a half click or quarter click.

For a conventional mouse, a single wheel click is reported as 120 wheelDeltaY "units" and results in *about* ~100px worth of scrolling. The physical wheelDeltaY unit is a completely arbitrary number, it is not measuring inches or degrees or anything like that. The number 120 was selected [simply because it has a lot of useful factors](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130123-00/?p=5473). The amount of scrolling on screen is represented by deltaY, and it [varies significantly by browser](https://github.com/facebookarchive/fixed-data-table/blob/master/src/vendor_upstream/dom/normalizeWheel.js). (Sidenote, deltaY is generally measured in "lines" not pixels, though it's complicated, see previous link).

[image: mouse cutaway]

Interacting with a trackpad is different in two ways. First of all, you can get wheelDeltaY values much smaller than 120, because very subtle finger gestures are detectable. Second, the wheelDeltaY is exactly 3x the deltaY value (at least in every browser I've managed to test). So, for instance, if you make a physical finger gesture equal to 12 click units, it will generally result in 4 pixels worth of scrolling. Lauri's code uses this second property (Y1 = Y2 * 3) to detect the existence of a trackpad, but you could probably also be successful simply by checking if abs(wheelDeltaY) equals 120

I haven't tested this, but I think it would also work:

```
function detectTrackPad(e) {
  var isTrackpad = false;
  if (e.wheelDeltaY) {
    if (Math.abs(e.wheelDeltaY) !== 120) {
      isTrackpad = true;
    }
  }
  else if (e.deltaMode === 0) {
    isTrackpad = true;
  }
  console.log(isTrackpad ? "Trackpad detected" : "Mousewheel detected");
}

document.addEventListener("mousewheel", detectTrackPad, false);
document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", detectTrackPad, false);
```

Comment: Excellent solution, working as expected. Just a note - if you are using this in jquery's `.on('mousewhell wheel') ...` callback, then don't forget to pass original event, not that event's wrapper: `detectTrackPad(e.originalEvent)`

Comment: Would be nice if you could get the direction and magnitude from this (Y direction) without needing the window to scroll (e.g. if y-overflow: hidden)

Comment: Safari gives wheelDelta 12 instead of 120 for one wheel click, and performs some odd acceleration calculation for rapid scrolling. Other browsers also may display 240 etc. for multiple scrolls within an event.

Comment: In Firefox, `deltaMode` is always 0, and `wheelDeltaY == -3 * deltaY` both for trackpad panning and wheel scrolling. `wheelDeltaY` is also a multiple of 16 rather than 120 in FF, which happens too frequently to be reliable, so I don't see a way to fix this in FF. In Chrome, `wheelDeltaY` may be larger multiples of 120, and has the `devicePixelRatio` multiplied in, and may still accidentally hit 120n from time to time. (This is tested on a Mac; it may be different on other systems).

Comment: Alas e.wheelDeltaY is deprecated

Comment: This answer is inaccurate today. It may have been correct at a certain time based on a certain set of browser+OS combinations, but today, I am definitely getting wrong values for all possible browser+OS combinations.

Answer (score 29):

Compare e.wheelDeltaY and e.deltaY (or e.deltaMode in Firefox) to detect touchpad mouse device

```js
function handler(e) {
    var isTouchPad = e.wheelDeltaY ? e.wheelDeltaY === -3 * e.deltaY : e.deltaMode === 0
    // your code
    document.body.textContent = isTouchPad ? "isTouchPad" : "isMouse"
}
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", handler, false);
document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", handler, false);
```

Comment: Conceptual explanation of why this works, plus some similar alternate strategies here https://stackoverflow.com/a/62415754/1209832

Comment: Just ran your code and tested with my touchpad, and boy did it switch quickly between `isTouchPad` and `isMouse`... But when using my mouse it didn't switch at all so there certainly is SOME truth to this.

Comment: Doesn't work with a magic mouse (got isTouchPad)

Comment: Magic Mouse is a touchpad when it comes to scrolling :D So that's correct.

Comment: On mac this reports mice with a scrollwheel as a touchpad

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Is there a way to find Magic Mouse?

Comment: This answer is inaccurate today. It may have been correct at a certain time based on a certain set of browser+OS combinations, but today, I am definitely getting wrong values for all possible browser+OS combinations.

Answer (score 22):

This topic may be already solved, but the answer was there is no way to detect it. Well I needed to get a solution, it was very important. So I found a acceptable solution for this problem:

```
var scrolling = false;
var oldTime = 0;
var newTime = 0;
var isTouchPad;
var eventCount = 0;
var eventCountStart;

var mouseHandle = function (evt) {
    var isTouchPadDefined = isTouchPad || typeof isTouchPad !== "undefined";
    console.log(isTouchPadDefined);
    if (!isTouchPadDefined) {
        if (eventCount === 0) {
            eventCountStart = new Date().getTime();
        }

        eventCount++;

        if (new Date().getTime() - eventCountStart > 100) {
                if (eventCount > 10) {
                    isTouchPad = true;
                } else {
                    isTouchPad = false;
                }
            isTouchPadDefined = true;
        }
    }

    if (isTouchPadDefined) {
        // here you can do what you want
        // i just wanted the direction, for swiping, so i have to prevent
        // the multiple event calls to trigger multiple unwanted actions (trackpad)
        if (!evt) evt = event;
        var direction = (evt.detail<0 || evt.wheelDelta>0) ? 1 : -1;

        if (isTouchPad) {
            newTime = new Date().getTime();

            if (!scrolling && newTime-oldTime > 550 ) {
                scrolling = true;
                if (direction < 0) {
                    // swipe down
                } else {
                    // swipe up
                }
                setTimeout(function() {oldTime = new Date().getTime();scrolling = false}, 500);
            }
        } else {
            if (direction < 0) {
                // swipe down
            } else {
                // swipe up
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And registering the events:

```
document.addEventListener("mousewheel", mouseHandle, false);
document.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", mouseHandle, false);
```

It may need some optimization and is maybe less than perfect, but it works! At least it can detect a macbook trackpad. But due to the design i'd say it should work anywhere where the pad introduces a lot of event calls.

Here is how it works:

When the user first scrolls, it will detect and check that in 50ms not more than 5 events got triggered, which is pretty unusual for a normal mouse, but not for a trackpad.

Then there is the else part, which is not for importance for the detection, but rather a trick to call a function once like when a user swipes. Please come at me if I wasn't clear enough, it was very tricky to get this working, and is of course a less than ideal workaround.

**Edit:** I optimized the code now as much as I can. It detects the mouseroll on the second time and swipe on trackpad instantly. Removed also a lot of repeating and unnecessary code.

**Edit 2** I changed the numbers for the time check and numbers of events called from 50 to 100 and 5 to 10 respectively. This should yield in a more accurate detection.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ucLe3hLa/) is a fiddle with this code for easier testing of end result.

Comment: Thanks. I use this code now on my production site and it works very well. I modified your fiddle to get an instant result: https://jsfiddle.net/ucLe3hLa/1/

Comment: The assumption of "not more than 5 events in 50ms" doesn't hold for my mouse. How did you come up with it?

Comment: It was just guessing from testing around 5 different mouses and 3 track pads. Does the fiddle report you are using a trackpad when youre using the mouse then?

Comment: Honestly if I touch a track pad a bit it thinks that I use Mouse. =(

Comment: Is this how you use a trackpad? Usually i scroll more than 20 pixels when im on a tracklpad

Comment: I updated my answer and the fiddle. It should work better now.

Comment: works only if you move fast on the touchpad - if I scroll slowly using this precision touchpad it says it's a mouse:(

Answer (score 5):

You could detect JS events.

A touch device will fire touch events such as `touchstart` in addition to mouse events.

A non-touch device will only fire the mouse events.

Comment: For anyone looking at this question recently, I've been searching around and I don't think this is true across all browsers, if any. Would love to see a source to show that trackpads trigger touch events.

Comment: @minorcase hmm...now that I re-read the question, I'm not sure if the OP was referring to handheld devices specifically, or any touch input peripheral. I agree, a touch pad (say, hooked up to a computer) wouldn't be *seen* as a touch device. My answer was specifically about the device as a whole (ie, a mobile browser vs desktop browser).

Comment: So, to be clear, yea, if we're talking about differentiating a mouse click from a touchpad click on something like a laptop, AFAIK, you can't differentiate those via JS.

Comment: Ah gotcha. I just assumed that they meant like a trackpad, but I just re-read it as well and the wording is kind of ambiguous. I just assumed they meant trackpad, but if they meant touch device then your answer is very correct! Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 5):

Wheel event triggered by touchpad will give much smaller event.deltaY,1 or 2,but trigger by mouse wheel will give like 100,200.

Comment: This is the best answer. Thank you!

Comment: Actually this is true to some extent but not always like if you scroll from touch pad and it gives you last value 1 then on mouse scroll, on first scroll it will give you same value 1 then after that it will change.

Answer (score 4):

Trust me. This is the easiest and only solution that also works for Safari (as far as I know).

```
isTrackPad(e) {
  const { deltaY } = e;
  if (deltaY && !Number.isInteger(deltaY)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: This marks the mouse also as trackpad on Mac. Didn't test on windows.

Comment: This actually works for me on Mac. Probably it depends on what mouse you use and how it sends the actual wheel value.

Answer (score 0):

From testing plugging in a mouse to a mac which does have a touchpad and also a windows machine with one, I can summarize how I got this working.

1. Detect if the navigator user agent contains "Mobile" or "Mac OS" If either
   of these are true, it is likely a touch based system, but work to
   eliminate that. Set boolean hasTouchPad to true
2. If the above is true, detect "mouse" events and run a test like high
       numbers, or a frequency of non integers or Kalman filtering.
3. Keep these in a queue and if that queue's sum passes a threshold,
       disable the hasTouchpad variable and disconnect the event.

```
let isMouseCounts: Array<number> = []

if (Client.hasTouchpad) {
    document.addEventListener('wheel', detectMouseType);
}

function detectMouseType(e:WheelEvent) {
    if (!Client.hasTouchpad) return

    let isMouse = e.deltaX === 0 && !Number.isInteger(e.deltaY)

    isMouseCounts.push(isMouse ? 1 : 0)
    if (isMouseCounts.length > 5) isMouseCounts.shift()

    let sum = isMouseCounts.reduce(function(a, b) { return a + b; });

    if (sum > 3 && e.type === "wheel") {
        console.log("Touchpad disabled")
        document.removeEventListener('wheel', detectMouseType);
        Client.hasTouchpad = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is typescript, right? Could you maybe provide a JS version? That's what the question asked for, and I have no way to test this solution without spinning up a whole webpack build.

Comment: just remove the types?

Answer (score -3):

You could just check for the device driver softwares installed into the local package as functioning. Like in windows synaptics, elan hardware, as for UNIX(Linux) you could just check for the package installed during the basic installed onto. A lot of packages come in different formats in different versions of Linux and Linux like systems(Not linux entirely) but they use the same package name for all. Just got to know the code to pull it. Still working on it.