# Get all series inside the axis and setinterval with min max

Tags: lightningchart

Hi I have one axis and multiple series inside it.I want to setInterval Y axis for max Y value and min Y value.

My question is can I setInterval for series instead of axis ? Because one of my series is from 50 to 100 and another is 200 to 500... sometimes min max is set in axis wrongly.

If I cannot setInterval for series, how do I get all the series inside axis so I will process min , max manually.

something like below , but for axis

```
chart.getSeries().forEach(series => {

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axis interval is configured on Axis, not Series.

You said you only have one Axis, which would mean that all your series are inside the same axis - why do you want to get all the series inside some axis? All series are created in application code, so you should be able to keep references to all of them, and make a list if you need.

Comment: I have 2 moving average in one axis.. I want to know which one's max and min should i use in the setinterval...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you are trying to achieve.