# In LightningChartJS, in Chart3D how to decrease zoom speed when pinching trackpad

Tags: lightningchart

I couldn't find a way to control the zoom speed when using the trackpad to zoom in/out in Chart3D.

In Chart2d I could do this by disabling the default mousewheel zoom and overriding the onSeriesBackgroundMouseWheel event. From this solution [Detect direction of touchpad swipe properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67794735/detect-direction-of-touchpad-swipe-properly)

However, in Chart3D there is no method of disabling mousewheel zoom and zooming the chart by setInterval.

Please help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your findings are correct, there is currently no way to alter the default user interactions of `Chart3D`.

We're currently targeting this feature to the next release v3.1 (late July), but at this time we can't say for sure if it will be included. In any case it will be coming this summer.

After this feature is published we can provide a code snippet here how the zooming can be customized in 3D also.

Additional mention is if you have no other issue with the default interaction than its sensitivity then I think that the better long term approach for LCJS development is to add API for just modifying sensitivity.

Comment: I would like to discuss this in further detail during our coming meeting where I can show you the demo yes?

Comment: Naturally will do