# Distinguish Trackpad and mouse on wheel event

Tags: javascript, web, web-frontend

How can I Distinguish that which device triggers `wheel` event

```js
node.addEventListener('wheel', handleWheel)
```

I want to do the following

1. For mouse wheel:  zoom in/out
2. For pinch via trackpad:  zoom in/out
3. For two finger pan: moving pan

I don't have questions about **zoom in/out** and **moving pan** action, these are Application specific action

My question is, How can I detect that the event is triggered by Mouse wheel or trackpad

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect touchpad vs mouse in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744645/detect-touchpad-vs-mouse-in-javascript)

Comment: No, I tried most of them. They don't work in latest chrome