# How can I detect Apple magic mouse / trackpad two finger touch events with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

For a site I need to move (transform) when the magic or mouse trackpad is used with two fingers. I tried to do it with the following code:

```
        document.getElementById('area').addEventListener('touchstart', function (e) {
            console.log("Mouse");
        });
```

I couldn't find any information regarding how to detect that with JavaScript. What would be the handler to that? Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect touchpad vs mouse in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744645/detect-touchpad-vs-mouse-in-javascript)

Comment: You can do this by detecting the amount of scrolling (as long as two-finger scrolling is a Mac thing, too). Check out [the MDN reference on scroll events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event).

Comment: I have been looking for a way to detect individual multi touches on track pads too and no, sadly enough, it's not possible. They just don't report them, as they're not "touches".

Comment: They usually are reported as other events, though. Here's one example: https://kenneth.io/post/detecting-multi-touch-trackpad-gestures-in-javascript